# regarding jar file in java

Tags: java, ubuntu

I want to create jar file in ubuntu linux.Can anybody help me or any link.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

for more information 
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html

If you are using eclipse IDE, instead of using command line tool you can use eclipse  to generate jar file for you.[This article shows how to do it](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html).

Following article shows how to do it in NetBeans 
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1):

Here yo go: [Creating a JAR File](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 1):

The jar tool is part of the Java SDK:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html